# Matched pair PNP usage

Tags: transistors

I am asking help to understand the circuit in the black rectangle below.
It’s using a matched pair of PNP, with common Base. I was thinking to a kind of current mirror, but R2 and R3 are different. I have looked in usage of matched pairs and I understand its main properties are equally matched gain.
Any ideas
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andy stated in [his answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/557943/103420), the main purpose of the whole circuit is to provide reverse-polarity protection by using the PMOS as an ideal diode.

Normally, you can get rid of the transistor pair at the bottom, and leave only the R3 (47k) connected to the gate. The circuit can still work and provide reverse-polarity protection:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEfz21.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The downside of the circuit above is that it does not protect either side when you apply a positive voltage on both sides. For example, when you apply a positive voltage from the right-hand side instead of the left-hand side, the MOSFET will turn on and provide voltage to the left-hand side. Think about what happens if the VIN is connected to the USB power and you accidentally applied a positive voltage to the VOUT-side.

That is the case the transistor pair's crucial role comes in. The pair ensures that the MOSFET remains off when the voltage is applied to the right-hand side instead of the left-hand side. Or generally, when there is a greater voltage on the right-hand side than that on the left-hand side.

[image]

Assume you applied a positive voltage to the right-hand side and left the left-hand side unconnected. The right part of the pair will turn on (because its base is connected to GND through R2) and connect the gate of Q3 to the source. So Q3 will be off. The same things apply when the voltage on the right-hand side is greater than that on the left-hand side.

So we can say that the pair prevents the MOSFET to work as a bidirectional switch. It does not provide protection when VOUT is lesser than VIN, though.

Answer (score 4):

> *I was thinking to a kind of current mirror, but R2 and R3 are
> different.*

R2 and R3 are usually different in a current mirror. They can be the same of course.

The circuit looks like it will control the gate-source voltage to ensure the MOSFET won't be damaged if the input supply is too high and positive. It may be some form of transient overload protection for the PMOSFET. However, the use of a zener/TVS device on the 5 volt rail suggests that anything significantly greater than 5 volts on the left-hand port for any length of time over a few tens of milliseconds and there will be smoke.

However, the main function of the circuit is to protect the 5 volt output rail (on the right) should there be a reversed supply at the input port (on the left). The PMOSFET will turn off if that happens.

Comment: The circuit also protects the left-hand side when the supply is applied to the right-hand side instead, or the voltage at the right-hand side is greater than that at the left-hand side.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I thought about that but the voltage arrow above the diode symbol implies the voltage supply comes from the left. But, who really knows?